# Como capturar value do select como string em PHP?

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um formulário em PHP, quando ele captura os dados de um select ele me retorna apenas como 0 ou 1, gostaria que ele mostrasse o que a pessoa selecionou:

```
<select class="form-control" name="pergunta1" required>
                                    <option selected="" value="">ESCOLHA SUA RESPOSTA</option>
                                    <option value="camuflado">CAMUFLADO</option>
                                    <option value="gancho">GANCHO</option>
                                    <option value="estimulante">ESTIMULANTE</option>
                                    <option value="lamina">LÂMINA SÔNICA</option>
                                    <option value="holopiloto">HOLOPILOTO</option>
                                    <option value="escudo">ESCUDO</option>
                                    <option value="cronossalto">CRONOSSALTO</option>
                                </select> 


<?php 
$resposta1 = isset($_GET['pergunta1'])?isset($_GET['pergunta1']):0;
$resposta2 = isset($_GET['pergunta2'])?isset($_GET['pergunta2']):0; 

echo "$resposta1";
?>
```

Quando ele retorna o echo ele retorna como 1 ou 0, gostaria que ele retornasse como string, por exemplo se a pessoa selecionou "camuflado" q retorne "camuflado" ao invés de 1 ou 0.

Comment: Que tal: `$resposta1 = isset($_GET['pergunta1'])?$_GET['pergunta1']:0;`?

Comment: mmmuuuuuiiiittooooo obrigado, sou novato demais ainda, to apanhando muito. ma vlww

Comment: De nada, boa sorte

Comment: e se eu precisar comparar este valor com if else?? por exemplo:

<?php 
$resposta1 = isset($_GET['pergunta1'])?($_GET['pergunta1']):0;
$resposta2 = isset($_GET['pergunta2'])?($_GET['pergunta2']):0; 

if($resposta1 = COMO COLOCO AQUI O VALUE "CAMUFLADO"?){
    echo "camuflado";
}  else {
    echo 'deu certo';
}
?>

Comment: deixa, consegui aqui rsrsr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está verificando duas vezes se a variável enviado para o GET é definida. Neste caso, basta utilizar:

```
$resposta1 = isset($_GET['pergunta1'])?$_GET['pergunta1']:0;
```

No exemplo acimá verificamos se a variável `$_GET['pergunta1']`, através da função `isset()`, é definida, se não atribuímos o valor 0 para `$_GET['pergunta1']`.

Referência: [Artigo](https://forjtreinamentos.wordpress.com/2016/05/24/novidades-do-php-7-2-operador-de-coalescencia-nula/).

Referências: [isset()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php), [estrutura if](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.if.php).

---

**EDIT:**

Existe também um novo operador de comparação chamado Coalescência Nula. Implementada a partir da versão 7.0 do PHP.

Ele basicamente substitui a função isset(). Por exemplo:

Sua linha atual de código é essa:

```
 $resposta1 = isset($_GET['pergunta1'])?$_GET['pergunta1']:0;
```

Com o Operador de Coalescência Nula ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
$resposta1 = $_GET['pergunta1'] ?? 0;
```

Você obterá o mesmo resultado, e isso ajudará a economizar tempo e linha em seus códigos.